# How can I access 'this' in props validator in Vue

Tags: vuejs2

I'd like to access a `computed` property in a props validator:

```
validator({ type, size }) {  
  return type === 'disabled' && hasLink()
}
```

and further down:

```
computed: {
  hasLink() {
    return this.link // another props accessed here
  }
},
```

But `hasLink` is undefined in the props validator. Any idea how I can access `this` in the props validator.

Comment: Is this a vue 1 or 2 question? why have you used both tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. [Prop Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation):

> Note that props are validated **before** a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. `data`, `computed`, etc) will not be available inside `default` or `validator` functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how do you suggest can I check in the props validator if another prop has been passed?

Comment: For example in the `created` hook as mentioned here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3495

Comment: But this does not have access to the validator neither, which means that I have to implement my own "failure" point here.